# Queries to server (images load)

Tags: php, web-services

I have a simple question which I don't understand completely.
So suppose I have the website on shared hosting, I have the main page which has 2 css files 2 js files, 35 images.

so question in when user open this page server must handle 'get query' + 2 queries for css + 2 queries to js + 35 queries to load images so we have 40 queries which we need to load a page?

So if we have another server for images, the main server could process more users which open web site?

Comment: Welcome to the world of [CDNs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Content_delivery_network), whose purpose is this exactly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> so question in when user open this page server must handle 'get query'
>   + 2 queries for css + 2 queries to js + 35 queries to load images so we have 40 queries which we need to load a page?

Yes. However note that with proper configuration of your web server, subsequent hits from the same browser will be cached.

> So if we have another server for images, the main server could process
>   more users which open web site?

Generally, yes. Moving images to a separate host is a popular way to distribute load. Note that if you're not actually experiencing problems right now, then it's probably too early to worry about how you're going to implement a solution, especially if your content is all static files.

Comment: I would add another web server to handle some of the client requests before ever making a server just for photos, that is unless you're hosting a photo sharing site of some kind.